# CodeIgniter Query not working need second pair of eyes

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have been working on this CodeIgniter Query for a couple of hours now and I can't figure out the problem. Here is the SQL Table with the data in it and the names of each field. The table name is bodystyle.

make |
model |
bodystyle

Ford |
F-150 Raptor 4X4 Crew Cab |
FRONT CAB

BMW | |

BMW | |
35i |

BMW |
X5 |
35i

BMW |
X5 |
45i

BMW |
X5 |
35i

Here is the query that I am running using CodeIgniter

```
$make =$this->input->post('make');
    $model =$this->input->post('model'); 


    $this->db->select('bodystyle');
    $this->db->from('bodystyle');
    $this->db->where('make', $make);
    $this->db->where('model', $model);
    $records = $this->db->get('');

    $output = null; 
    foreach ($records->result() as $row){

    $output .=  $row->bodystyle . ', ';
    }

    echo $output;

$make = Ford

$model = Raptor 4X4 Crew Cab
```

The output I am getting is `FRONT CAB, ,35i, 45i, 35i`

Can you see any reason why it is pulling all the bodystyles?

I want it just to pull it based off of the Make and Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that column name in select clause and table name both are same. Make sure you have provided the correct column name and table name. Below is the edited query please check it.

your result query should be

```
$records->result('array')
```

instead of

```
$records->result()
```

Try:

```
$make =$this->input->post('make');
$model =$this->input->post('model'); 


$this->db->select(column_name);
$this->db->from(table_name);
$this->db->where(array(
'make' => $make,
'model' => $model
));
$records = $this->db->get();
$result = $records->result('array');

print_r($result);
```

Comment: The table name and column name are the same, I tried making them unique and it still yielded the same results

Comment: @user2411269 try $records->result('array')

Comment: I believe it is a problem with my ajax, I am sending Make and model through the data portion of my ajax and when I output them it is empty

Comment: can you please provide sample data with table structure and your ajax code?

Comment: Problem was I was using $this->input->post instead of $this->input->get

Stupid mistake, thanks for your help!